# Angularjs connect to multiple sockets.io

Tags: angularjs, node.js, multithreading, socket.io

I have two nodes running socket.io on different ports.

My code includes the scripts

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//example.com:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//example.com:8081/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

creates the two services

```
app.factory("socket", function(){
  var socket = io.connect("http://example.com:8080");
  return socket;
}).factory("socket2", function(){
  var socket2 = io.connect("http://example.com:8081");
  return socket2;
});
```

and in some controller I inject and try to communicate with both of them.

```
app.controller('someCtrl', function($scope, socket, socket2,...
```

It works with the first one but not with the second.

The second socket is working cause it actually serves some other clients, but I'm not being able to emit or receive from that socket.

For testing made two identical nodes and still couldn't connect to the second one.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to reference the 'socket.io.js' script twice, this may be causing an issue by overwriting something. Try that and see if it works.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="socket.io.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var socket1 = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3000');
var socket2 = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3001');

socket1.on('new message', function (data) {
  console.log('1st server');
});

socket2.on('new message', function (data) {
  console.log('2nd server');
});

</script>
```

Comment: I just tested this with basic javascript (no angular) and it worked just fine.